# sorting multiple integers by ascending order in java

Tags: java, sorting

So I've been racking my head for the past 6 hours trying to accomplish this task and I've gotten nowhere. I have a bunch of integers that I want to sort in ascending order for a class assignment. However, I cant use anything fancy, IE .sort or anything that I need to important into Java. The only alternative I've been able to come up with is to use if statements and list every possible combination of 8 numbers; but that seems excessive, there's got to be a better way.

This is the section of my code I've been dealing with. I basically want to sort d1-d8 in ascending order. I've tried arrays as well, but to no avail.

On a side note I'm sure my code is way longer then it needs to be, but I'm pretty new at this and I dont really want to reformat it.

```
        else if (a1 >= 1){
          int a21 = 0;
          int a31 = 0;
          int a41 = 0;
          int a51 = 0;
          int a61 = 0;
          int a71 = 0;
          int a81 = 0;
          int a91 = 0;
          int d1 = 0;
          int d2 = 0;
          int d3 = 0;
          int d4 = 0;
          int d5 = 0;
          int d6 = 0;
          int d7 = 0;
          int d8 = 0;
          if ((a2 % a1) == (a2 % a1)) a21 = a21 + 1; 
          if ((a2 % a1) == (a3 % a1)) a21 = a21 + 1; 
          if ((a2 % a1) == (a4 % a1)) a21 = a21 + 1; 
          if ((a2 % a1) == (a5 % a1)) a21 = a21 + 1; 
          if ((a2 % a1) == (a6 % a1)) a21 = a21 + 1; 
          if ((a2 % a1) == (a7 % a1)) a21 = a21 + 1; 
          if ((a2 % a1) == (a8 % a1)) a21 = a21 + 1; 
          if ((a2 % a1) == (a9 % a1)) a21 = a21 + 1; 
          if ((a3 % a1) == (a2 % a1)) a31 = a31 + 1; 
          if ((a3 % a1) == (a3 % a1)) a31 = a31 + 1; 
          if ((a3 % a1) == (a4 % a1)) a31 = a31 + 1; 
          if ((a3 % a1) == (a5 % a1)) a31 = a31 + 1; 
          if ((a3 % a1) == (a6 % a1)) a31 = a31 + 1; 
          if ((a3 % a1) == (a7 % a1)) a31 = a31 + 1;
          if ((a3 % a1) == (a8 % a1)) a31 = a31 + 1; 
          if ((a3 % a1) == (a9 % a1)) a31 = a31 + 1; 
          if ((a4 % a1) == (a2 % a1)) a41 = a41 + 1; 
          if ((a4 % a1) == (a3 % a1)) a41 = a41 + 1; 
          if ((a4 % a1) == (a4 % a1)) a41 = a41 + 1; 
          if ((a4 % a1) == (a5 % a1)) a41 = a41 + 1; 
          if ((a4 % a1) == (a6 % a1)) a41 = a41 + 1; 
          if ((a4 % a1) == (a7 % a1)) a41 = a41 + 1; 
          if ((a4 % a1) == (a8 % a1)) a41 = a41 + 1; 
          if ((a4 % a1) == (a9 % a1)) a41 = a41 + 1; 
          if ((a5 % a1) == (a2 % a1)) a51 = a51 + 1; 
          if ((a5 % a1) == (a3 % a1)) a51 = a51 + 1; 
          if ((a5 % a1) == (a4 % a1)) a51 = a51 + 1; 
          if ((a5 % a1) == (a5 % a1)) a51 = a51 + 1; 
          if ((a5 % a1) == (a6 % a1)) a51 = a51 + 1; 
          if ((a5 % a1) == (a7 % a1)) a51 = a51 + 1;
          if ((a5 % a1) == (a8 % a1)) a51 = a51 + 1;
          if ((a5 % a1) == (a9 % a1)) a51 = a51 + 1;
          if ((a6 % a1) == (a2 % a1)) a61 = a61 + 1; 
          if ((a6 % a1) == (a3 % a1)) a61 = a61 + 1; 
          if ((a6 % a1) == (a4 % a1)) a61 = a61 + 1; 
          if ((a6 % a1) == (a5 % a1)) a61 = a61 + 1; 
          if ((a6 % a1) == (a6 % a1)) a61 = a61 + 1; 
          if ((a6 % a1) == (a7 % a1)) a61 = a61 + 1; 
          if ((a6 % a1) == (a8 % a1)) a61 = a61 + 1; 
          if ((a6 % a1) == (a9 % a1)) a61 = a61 + 1; 
          if ((a7 % a1) == (a2 % a1)) a71 = a71 + 1; 
          if ((a7 % a1) == (a3 % a1)) a71 = a71 + 1; 
          if ((a7 % a1) == (a4 % a1)) a71 = a71 + 1; 
          if ((a7 % a1) == (a5 % a1)) a71 = a71 + 1; 
          if ((a7 % a1) == (a6 % a1)) a71 = a71 + 1; 
          if ((a7 % a1) == (a7 % a1)) a71 = a71 + 1;
          if ((a7 % a1) == (a8 % a1)) a71 = a71 + 1;
          if ((a7 % a1) == (a9 % a1)) a71 = a71 + 1;
          if ((a8 % a1) == (a2 % a1)) a81 = a81 + 1; 
          if ((a8 % a1) == (a3 % a1)) a81 = a81 + 1; 
          if ((a8 % a1) == (a4 % a1)) a81 = a81 + 1; 
          if ((a8 % a1) == (a5 % a1)) a81 = a81 + 1; 
          if ((a8 % a1) == (a6 % a1)) a81 = a81 + 1; 
          if ((a8 % a1) == (a7 % a1)) a81 = a81 + 1;
          if ((a8 % a1) == (a8 % a1)) a81 = a81 + 1;
          if ((a8 % a1) == (a9 % a1)) a81 = a81 + 1;
          if ((a9 % a1) == (a2 % a1)) a91 = a91 + 1; 
          if ((a9 % a1) == (a3 % a1)) a91 = a91 + 1; 
          if ((a9 % a1) == (a4 % a1)) a91 = a91 + 1; 
          if ((a9 % a1) == (a5 % a1)) a91 = a91 + 1; 
          if ((a9 % a1) == (a6 % a1)) a91 = a91 + 1; 
          if ((a9 % a1) == (a7 % a1)) a91 = a91 + 1;
          if ((a9 % a1) == (a8 % a1)) a91 = a91 + 1;
          if ((a9 % a1) == (a9 % a1)) a91 = a91 + 1;
          if (a2 <= 0) d1 = (((a2 % a1) + a1) % a1);
          else d1 = (a2 % a1);
          if (a3 <= 0) d2 = (((a3 % a1) + a1) % a1); 
          else d2 = (a3 % a1);
          if (a4 <= 0) d3 = (((a4 % a1) + a1) % a1); 
          else d3 = (a4 % a1);
          if (a5 <= 0) d4 = (((a5 % a1) + a1) % a1); 
          else d4 = (a5 % a1);
          if (a6 <= 0) d5 = (((a6 % a1) + a1) % a1); 
          else d5 = (a6 % a1);
          if (a7 <= 0) d6 = (((a7 % a1) + a1) % a1); 
          else d6 = (a7 % a1);
          if (a8 <= 0) d7 = (((a8 % a1) + a1) % a1);
          else d7 = (a8 % a1);
          if (a9 <= 0) d8 = (((a9 % a1) + a1) % a1);
          else d8 = (a9 % a1);
          System.out.println(d1 + ": " + a21); 
          if((a2 % a1)!= (a3 % a1)){ System.out.println(d2 + ": "+ a31);}
          if((a2 % a1)!= (a4 % a1)){ if((a3 % a1)!= (a4 % a1)){ System.out.println(d3 + ": " + a41);}}
          if((a2 % a1)!= (a5 % a1)){ if((a3 % a1)!= (a5 % a1)){ if((a4 % a1)!= (a5 % a1)){ System.out.println(d4 + ": " + a51);}}}
          if((a2 % a1)!= (a6 % a1)){ if((a3 % a1)!= (a6 % a1)){ if((a4 % a1)!= (a6 % a1)){ if ((a5 % a1)!= (a6 % a1)){ System.out.println(d5 + ": "+ a61);}}}}
          if((a2 % a1)!= (a7 % a1)){ if((a3 % a1)!= (a7 % a1)){ if((a4 % a1)!= (a7 % a1)){ if ((a5 % a1)!= (a7 % a1)){if ((a6 % a1)!= (a7 % a1)){  System.out.println(d6 + ": " + a71);}}}}}
          if((a2 % a1)!= (a8 % a1)){ if((a3 % a1)!= (a8 % a1)){ if((a4 % a1)!= (a8 % a1)){ if ((a5 % a1)!= (a8 % a1)){if ((a6 % a1)!= (a8 % a1)){if((a7 % a1)!= (a8 % a1))  System.out.println(d7 + ": " + a81);}}}}}
          if((a2 % a1)!= (a9 % a1)){ if((a3 % a1)!= (a9 % a1)){ if((a4 % a1)!= (a9 % a1)){ if ((a5 % a1)!= (a9 % a1)){if ((a6 % a1)!= (a9 % a1)){if((a7 % a1)!= (a9 % a1))if((a8 % a1)!= (a9 % a1)){ System.out.println(d8 + ": " + a91);}}}}}}
        }
```

Comment: Did you try Arrays.sort()  ?

Comment: @Kakarot He says in his post he can't use built-in sort methods.

Comment: Take a look at this rundown of [Quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) and see if you can implement it.

Comment: **"On a side note I'm sure my code is way longer then it needs to be...and I dont [sic] really want to reformat it."** -- It is, and you are going to have to.  What you have now is basically unreadable.  You need to rewrite this using an array of `int` and implement a sorting algorithm on it.

Answer (score 2):

Bubble sort, the dumbest sort in the world:

```
public static void sort(int[] items) {
    for (int i = 0; i < items.length - 1; ++i) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < items.length; ++j) {
            if (items[i] > items[j]) {
                int temp = items[i];
                items[i] = items[j];
                items[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Put your values in an array:

```
int[] items = new int[] { d1, d2, d3, ... };
```

And call sort on it:

```
sort(items);
```

After this, the content of `items` will be sorted, in ascending order.

Answer (score 1):

Please, no.

Find an algorithm book and write a simple sort method that takes an array and sorts it.  Even a bubble sort would be better than what you posted.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment ? How is it answer ?

Answer (score 0):

How about put everything in an array and call sort().

```
int[] arr = {10,1,30};
Arrays.sort(arr);
```

If you want to write the sort logic yourself, look at any of the sorting algorithms (merge sort, quick sort, insertion sort, etc).

Comment: He says in his post that he can't use .sort.

Comment: The OP was very clear that built-in sorting methods are not allowed.

Comment: The second part of my answer is for that. I believe his assignment is to implement a sorting algorithm. Else how can you sort a bunch of numbers without actually sorting it?

Comment: Here's a link to implementation of merge sort: https://github.com/adeydas/amazonpreps/blob/master/src/ws/abhis/amazonpreps/algorithms/MergeSort.java which I believe is the best in this scenario as it will lead to a worst time complexity of nlgn.

Answer (score 0):

One method, and not the most efficient, is to take the first number, and compare it to each number in your list.

If you don't find a number that is bigger you put this in position on in your array, and start over again with the next number in your list.
Otherwise if you find a number that is bigger than your number, you take that number and start from the front of your list looking for a number that is bigger than it.

You do this until you have compared each number.

It is worth looking sorting, as it is a wide area of research, with a number of different sort techniques, from the bubble sort to the quick sort.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a merge sort. That's easy enough.

```
import java.util.*;

public class MergeSort
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Integer[] a = {2, 6, 3, 5, 1};
    mergeSort(a);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
}

public static void mergeSort(Comparable [ ] a)
{
    Comparable[] tmp = new Comparable[a.length];
    mergeSort(a, tmp,  0,  a.length - 1);
}


private static void mergeSort(Comparable [ ] a, Comparable [ ] tmp, int left, int right)
{
    if( left < right )
    {
        int center = (left + right) / 2;
        mergeSort(a, tmp, left, center);
        mergeSort(a, tmp, center + 1, right);
        merge(a, tmp, left, center + 1, right);
    }
}


private static void merge(Comparable[ ] a, Comparable[ ] tmp, int left, int right, int rightEnd )
{
    int leftEnd = right - 1;
    int k = left;
    int num = rightEnd - left + 1;

    while(left <= leftEnd && right <= rightEnd)
        if(a[left].compareTo(a[right]) <= 0)
            tmp[k++] = a[left++];
        else
            tmp[k++] = a[right++];

    while(left <= leftEnd)    // Copy rest of first half
        tmp[k++] = a[left++];

    while(right <= rightEnd)  // Copy rest of right half
        tmp[k++] = a[right++];

    // Copy tmp back
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++, rightEnd--)
        a[rightEnd] = tmp[rightEnd];
}
}
```

Full disclosure

https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Sorting%20Algorithms/code/MergeSort.java